# Append command to history without removing last command

Tags: bash, shell

I use `fzf` for a lot of things. I will often pipe the output of `fzf` and run another command with the result. However, I often want to save that command to my `bash_history` so I can run it again without needing to find the item with `fzf` again. To do so, I use the `history -s` command. From the output of `help history`:

```
history: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or history -ps arg [arg...]
    Display or manipulate the history list.
...
      -s    append the ARGs to the history list as a single entry
```

However, it appears to *also* delete the last item in the history (i.e. the command that contained `fzf`). This is supported by the man page for bash-builtins I found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html).

```
...
       history -s arg [arg ...]
...
              -s     Store  the  args in the history list as a single entry.  The last command in
                     the history list is removed before the args are added.
```

Is there a way to prevent the last command from being removed? If possible, I would like to have both the `fzf` command *and* the command that was later executed appear in my history.

#### Additional details

- Bash version: 5.0.11(1)-release
- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020)

Comment: Tested with Bash 4.2.46, `history -s` does not remove the last entry. It does not add the `history -s` command itself, though.

Comment: @vdavid I forgot to include which Bash version, sorry! It's Bash 5.0.11(1) in my case.

Comment: I have the same issue with [`argrelay`](https://github.com/argrelay/argrelay) - an attempt to save command line query on [`Alt+Shift+Q`](https://github.com/argrelay/argrelay/blob/v0.6.2.final/src/argrelay/custom_integ_res/argrelay_rc.bash#L122-L127) replaces the last command in history.